# Flutter showModalBottomSheet does not allow transparent background container

Tags: flutter

Am I using some widget here incorrectly or is this an issue with [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)?

As you can see here in the screenshots, the test code I've included displays a button in a 70% transparent container. This looks correct in main body. However, when you tap the Open Bottom Sheet button to display the `showModalBottomSheet()` function you'll see that that exact same button in a container with 70% transparent bg color is now 100% opaque.

Why is the opacity of the container being ignored in the showModalBottomSheet widget tree?

I've tried using Opacity widget and a Stack, but transparency does not seem to be allowed in a showModalBottomSheet?

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BottomSheet(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheet({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _showBottomSheet() {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 27.0, bottom: 27.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Select',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 25.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 25.0,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 100.0,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                        Placeholder(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 161.0,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 24.0,
                      right: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: OutlinedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Button in container with 70% transparent bg ignored',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                          minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 52.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: const Radius.circular(32.0),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(32.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: const Radius.circular(32.0),
            topRight: const Radius.circular(32.0),
          ),
        ),
        barrierColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
        isScrollControlled: true,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Open bottom sheet',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: _showBottomSheet,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 161.0,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 24.0,
                  right: 24.0,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Button in container with 70% transparent bg',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 52.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try giving your `Container` (the first one, that you return from the `showModalBottomSheet()` function) a `color` propery of color you want your `BottomSheet` to have?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting. Please include some code. I'm not trying to give the bottomsheet a color. It is the Container the OutlinedButton resides in, in the BottomSheet, that I want to be semi-transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can [see here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79651), it appears to be a bug in Flutter's `showModalBottomSheet()`.

To overcome this, I built my own bottom sheet in a `Stack` to get the transparency affect I needed on the bottom sheet button.